# How to deal with changing JavaScript files for debugging?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

**The Reason :**

I have a complex web application that consists of many iframes on a single page. It was designed this way so that the pages in the iframes could be debugged and reloaded without reloading the whole page. Unfortunately since the [JSD2 implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger-API), iframes do not reload properly within Firebug's *Script* panel or the Firefox developer tools' *Debugger* panel.

I am wondering if I should stop waiting for the above issue to be fixed or change to a single page format and reload the HTML, CSS & JavaScript for each panel dynamically.

The problem I am having with this is reloading the `<script>` elements. It seems you cannot load more code into a `<script>` element that already contains a file. You must delete the element and create a new one. This results in a loss of breakpoints and a long list of defunct listings in the source list in the *Debugger*/*Script* panel.

**The Question :**

What is the best way to reload a revised JavaScript file in a page, when one does not wish to reload the whole page?

Comment: Have you tried livereload?

Comment: @Jorge Vivas: Just loaded & tried livereload, looks like a javascript change still reloads the whole page. Tried it within an iframe but would only work once & lose the connection to the livereload socket. Will use this for CSS though, Thanks!

Comment: Can you use firebugs cd command line expression? https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Cd

Comment: @kevinius I don't see how cd would help, Does not have anything to do with loading js files.